# Play a course created by another local user

Tags: super-mario-maker

In Super Mario Maker, I've created a course under my user profile. I would like my son to be able to play that course. Is this possible without publishing the course?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. The only way for ANYONE other than you to play your course, is by publishing it. Can you not let your son play the course on your account/Wii U?

Comment: Such a shame.  They missed a great opportunity for users on the same console to share.  Would also really help for offline players.